# Is there a way to suppress MOTD when starting up R?

Tags: r, startup

R loads a long and redundant message every time I start up. Is there a way to clear this using a command in my `.rprofile`?

Currently I just let it load then press ⌘ + L to clear it but it would be nice to just do it automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about the --quiet startup option?
For me on Ubuntu :

```
$ R --quiet
>
```

Comment: Just in case this sends anyone else looking for a list of the command line arguments for R, they're [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Is there a way to make this --quiet mode the default behavior?

Comment: In Linux try `alias R='R --quiet'`