# import rpy quietly

Tags: python, r, rpy2

My question is analogous to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319344/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-motd-when-starting-up-r) but in the context of importing R to Python via RPy. Specifically, when I run

```
from rpy import *
```

at the beginning of my python script, there is a chunk of message dumped to the screen (or output device), starting with

```
Parsing output:  R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
... ...
```

I wanted to implement the `quiet_require` from [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/robjects_rpackages.html) but don't see how it fits in the context of importing *all* modules.

I know this is possible because the same program running on another box doesn't output any message.

UPDATE: this does *not* have to be solved within Python. If I can somehow tweak a variable on the R side to allow all invocations to be quiet, that works too. I just don't know how to do that.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but it using `from package import *` is highly discouraged as it pollutes the global namespace. If you don't want to type rpy all the time, you can shorten it with `import rpy as R`.

Comment: You need to get R to start with the `--quiet` option.

Comment: May I ask why can't you use `rpy2` directly instead of `rpy`?

Comment: @Richie Cotton, yes, that would work too. But how?

Comment: @jcollado, I don't have full control on what gets installed on that box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is simple but not beatiful hack:

```
# define somewhere following:
import sys
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def quiet():
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__


# use it    
with quiet(): 
    # all is quiet in this scope
    import this  # just for testing
    from rpy import *  # or whatever you want
# and this will print something
import something_that_prints
```

**edit:** changed code as advised @jdi and @jcollado.

Comment: Could DummyFile() also be replaced with: `open(os.devnull, "w")` ? I like this contextmanager approach BTW

Comment: You can find similar solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8522689/183066). There are some changes that would make the code even better in my opinion: using `os.devnull` and using `sys.__stderr__` and `sys.__stdout__` to get the original `sys.stderr` and `sys.stdout` (no need to keep the values).

Comment: @jdi, jcollado, i like your advices. Added improvements to code.